# How to get the user data from Facebook in Android

Tags: android, facebook

I´m trying to set a Facebook Button on my app to login, but I have a problem, when I pulse the button it says me "Your login" and when I start my app say "log out" (becaouse I´m login autmatically)  but I cant get the information about the profile, I have this code:

```
package com.utad.clasi.facebook;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private View otherView;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    //private String welcome = getResources().getString(R.string.welcome);
    private  LoginButton loginButton;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private AccessToken accessToken;
    private Profile profile;
    private TextView txtProfileDetails;
    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> myCallBack = new     FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

        if(profile != null){
            txtProfileDetails.setText("Welcome" + profile.getFirstName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {

    }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    setLoginButton();


    txtProfileDetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtWelcomeProfile);



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

   public void setLoginButton(){
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, myCallBack);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode,  Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, myCallBack);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

I just want be able to save name and lastname from the profile into 2 variables. But I can´t do this. I would like to know the momment when my app makes a login to facebook to get them. Thank, d any suggestion or comments will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I forget 2 lines of code in onCreate:

```
    Profile actualProfile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    String name = actualProfile.getName();
```

With Profile.getCurrentProfile you can see what profile is loggin in your app.